# Get network status type in PhoneGap-Android without pinging the host

Tags: android, cordova

I have PhoneGap-Android application and I want to check network connection type (No connection, WIFI, GSM) by using PhoneGap API as described in http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_network_network.md.html

However, I don't need to check if specific hostname is reachable. The only thing I need to know is the connection type, so no ping to internet will occur.

I've tried variants such as these, but with no luck:

```
navigator.network.isReachable(null, reachableCallback);
navigator.network.isReachable(false, reachableCallback);
navigator.network.isReachable('', reachableCallback);
```

Is there a way how to get network connection type without actually accessing the internet in PhoneGap Android app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment there is no way to do this.

you can always write a plugin for phonegap to achieve what you want in native code. Here is a good entry on how to write a plugin: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap-Plugins

I am sorry but I have no good suggeestion how to write that functionality in Java for Android.

Comment: Oh well, I was hoping for some kind of miracle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.9.6 there is new API called Connection which solves just this problem. Take a look at http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html

Comment: That is really inconsistent on android though.  I get Connection.UNKNOWN returned for both 3G and 4G connections on my Nexus S.  Pinging the server really is the most reliable way if navigator.network.connection.type is "unknown".  Since it's inconsistent across devices, use "unknown" as an indicator you should manually test it.

Comment: Yes, it is inconsistent on Android (HTC Desire X, 4.0.1). It is ok when my phone uses 3G but I get Connection.NONE when it is using WIFI.